# Create a private Key from a PositiveSSL Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, rsa

I've just receive a certificate, containing those files:

```
- Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- Intermediate CA Certificate - USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
- Intermediate CA Certificate - SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
- Your PositiveSSL Certificate - www_guerrilla_app.crt
```

and also the PositiveSSL Certificate in text format.

I would like to know if it is possible to generete the Private Key from the command line, maybe using Java or other tool

Comment: Your private key should already be in the keystore you used to generate the CSR that you then sent off to the CA. See @Kees Hoekzema's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you could it would mean the entire https internet is broken. You need the key from whoever generated the CSR.

The proper workflow is: create a SSL key, generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) with that key, provide the CSR to the SSL Certificate provider (PositiveSSL), have them sign it and give you a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Kees answered - you will generate CSR and private key together. This private key you will required when add them to load balancer to nginx